# How do I check for a DKIM-signature? (Postfix)

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, dkim

I'm running Postfix on my Debian client and I'm trying to setup DKIM. The problem I'm having is that the mails do not seem to get signed by DKIM.

I'm using telnet to send an email from one local user to another using my local domain. When I'm opening the email I can't see any DKIM-signature as they can in [this guide](https://tecadmin.net/setup-dkim-with-postfix-on-ubuntu-debian/) (step 6).

This is /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unath_destination, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service, unix:private/policy-spf
myhostname = debian.lan
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = debian.lan, mcduckcorp.duckburg.cali, localhost.com, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892
```

This is /etc/opendkim.conf:

```
# This is a basic configuration that can easily be adapted to suit a standard
# installation. For more advanced options, see opendkim.conf(5) and/or
# /usr/share/doc/opendkim/examples/opendkim.conf.sample.

# Log to syslog
Syslog          yes
# Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
# privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
# UMask         007

# Sign for example.com with key in /etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key using
# selector '2007' (e.g. 2007._domainkey.example.com)
Domain          my.example.domain
KeyFile         /etc/mail/dkim.key
Selector        mail
Socket          inet:8892@localhost

# Commonly-used options; the commented-out versions show the defaults.
#Canonicalization   simple
Mode            sv
SubDomains      yes

# Socket smtp://localhost
#
# ##  Socket socketspec
# ##
# ##  Names the socket where this filter should listen for milter connections
# ##  from the MTA.  Required.  Should be in one of these forms:
# ##
# ##  inet:port@address           to listen on a specific interface
# ##  inet:port                   to listen on all interfaces
# ##  local:/path/to/socket       to listen on a UNIX domain socket


##  PidFile filename
###      default (none)
###
###  Name of the file where the filter should write its pid before beginning
###  normal operations.
#
PidFile               /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid


# Always oversign From (sign using actual From and a null From to prevent
# malicious signatures header fields (From and/or others) between the signer
# and the verifier.  From is oversigned by default in the Debian pacakge
# because it is often the identity key used by reputation systems and thus
# somewhat security sensitive.
OversignHeaders     From

##  ResolverConfiguration filename
##      default (none)
##
##  Specifies a configuration file to be passed to the Unbound library that
##  performs DNS queries applying the DNSSEC protocol.  See the Unbound
##  documentation at http://unbound.net for the expected content of this file.
##  The results of using this and the TrustAnchorFile setting at the same
##  time are undefined.
##  In Debian, /etc/unbound/unbound.conf is shipped as part of the Suggested
##  unbound package

# ResolverConfiguration     /etc/unbound/unbound.conf

##  TrustAnchorFile filename
##      default (none)
##
## Specifies a file from which trust anchor data should be read when doing
## DNS queries and applying the DNSSEC protocol.  See the Unbound documentation
## at http://unbound.net for the expected format of this file.

TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key

##  Userid userid
###      default (none)
###
###  Change to user "userid" before starting normal operation?  May include
###  a group ID as well, separated from the userid by a colon.
#
UserID                opendkim
```

This is /etc/default/opendkim

```
# Command-line options specified here will override the contents of
# /etc/opendkim.conf. See opendkim(8) for a complete list of options.
#DAEMON_OPTS=""
# Change to /var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim to use a Unix socket with
# postfix in a chroot:
#RUNDIR=/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim
RUNDIR=/var/run/opendkim
#
# Uncomment to specify an alternate socket
# Note that setting this will override any Socket value in opendkim.conf
# default:
#SOCKET=local:$RUNDIR/opendkim.sock
# listen on all interfaces on port 54321:
#SOCKET=inet:54321
# listen on loopback on port 12345:
SOCKET=inet:8892@localhost
# listen on 192.0.2.1 on port 12345:
#SOCKET=inet:12345@192.0.2.1
USER=opendkim
GROUP=opendkim
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/$NAME.pid
EXTRAAFTER=
```

My DNS-file has a TXT record for the public DKIM-key and the private-key is also configured.

Comment: misleading question - checking for a dkim signature means checking incoming mail from external hosts to postfix. badly worded.

Answer (score 1):

DKIM signing doesn’t make a lot of sense for locally delivered mail - the server assumes it can trust itself. Try sending mail to an external domain and look at those headers instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a school assignment and I'm apparently supposed to see a DKIM-signature when I'm opening the mail even when sending to a localhost.